# Integral of reciprocal of Gauss hypergeometric function

Tags: integration

I'm solving a indefinite integral, which involving the quadratic of the reciprocal of Gauss hypergeometric function. I have no idea to get the answer, so I come to ask for help.

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: It is advised to write the question in Latex and to not upload images. Here you can find a guide. Welcome! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Comment: There is no link to the image description.